# Can I use a SharePoint Calculated Column for a Text String?

Tags: sharepoint, calculated-columns, sharepoint-list

I am looking to create an ID column based off of the text in 4 other columns. I have tried =CONCATENATE(Col1,"-",Col2,"-",Col3) in a couple different ways and I still get errors.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with the formula you mentioned and it works fine in my list.
[image]
[image]

Would you like to provide a screenshot of the edit column page and the error page?